# How can I run php file using terminal using apache permissions?

Tags: php, apache, fedora

I have created a php file to create some directories. How can I run it using apache. I know you can run php like :

```
php /path/to/file
```

But what I need is : Can apache run commands in terminal, or using root can I tell that the current user is apache.

My OS is fedora 20

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into SSH
2. change chmod of the script to be able to be run (by other users if apache user does not own it) `chmod 700 /path/to/script` (or chmod 770 or 777 but the last digit should always be 0 for security reason)
3. change user to www-data or apache `su www-data` (the Apache username is set in Apache config file, probably `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache/httpd.conf`)
4. run the script using [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) `/path/to/script` or if you are in the scripts directory use `./script`
5. **or** run the script by passing it directly to php - `php /path/to/script`

Note 1: You can run the script by root too and `chown` the created files to apache user

Note 2: `php.ini` for console run scripts is most probably under `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`